# How does the integrity of data been validated in a transaction by the receiver in order to accept that transaction by the receiver, in Corda?

Tags: corda

How the receiver verify a proposed transaction before accepting to make sure its a valid proposal, ie how do they check the transaction chain to make sure the same.

If its going through all the previous transactions it going going be costly and affect the TPS.

Is it possible for the receiver to goto the notary and get it verified, by any chance?

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

1. At the receiver end, the transaction is being validated in the
   related responder flow. Example can be found here:
   https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/blacklist/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/examples/attachments/flow/ReachAgreementFlow.kt#L42
2. Speaking of the verification for the entire transaction chain, it is not handled by the receiver anyway. It is handled by the Notary (When you turn the validation feature on). More details can be found: https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-notaries.html

Comment: Ok, how does the verification happens in case non-validating notary then?